# Why is the DataGrid column binding not breaking MVVM structure?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagridview, decoupling

I am **not** experienced with WPF/MVVM, this is probably not a well founded question.

In the basic MVVM structure of a WPF MVVM Form, I believe I am right in saying that it can take a form similar to that which I have included in the footer of this message. *This is purely demonstrational code made purely for this question, haven't really checked it.*

What I don't understand is that, in the View, the DataGrid is linked to the 'Companies' Enumerable/Collection. This is completely fine, but when the column is then subsequently linked to 'Name' (A property of the object type Company (the model)) why is this not breaking the MVVM structure, the view is seemingly directly referencing the Model?

Is it not better to create a Collection of Objects in the ViewModel which then have properties REFERENCING the properties of the underlying model. This way, should the model change it's property names, only the ViewModel mapping needs to be changed as opposed to the View?

Perhaps I am I missing a step which performs something similar, or have missed something fundamental in MVVM understanding?

Thank you for any guidance.

**Demonstration of MVVM Structure**

**View:**

```
<DataGrid ItemSource={Binding Path="Companies"} AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Model:**

```
public class Company{
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public Company(string name){
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class DataGridViewModel{
    public DataGridViewModel(){
        this.Companies = new ObservableCollection<Company>();
        this.Companies.Add(new Company(test1));
        this.Companies.Add(new Company(test2));
        this.Companies.Add(new Company(test3));
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Company> Companies{get;set;}
}
```

**View.cs:**

```
public ViewCS()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new DataGridViewModel();
}
```

Comment: MVVM is not about strict senseless rules that bring no benefit, MVVM is about making your business logic completely separate from the UI, which makes sense and makes everyone happier. Your code is OK.

Comment: Who said the view can't know about the model?  http://i.imgur.com/wTrEucK.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is perfectly, 100% compatible with MVVM.

Saying that the view has absolutely *no knowledge* of the structure of the data it is displaying is crazy. It *has* to know stuff about that. Otherwise concepts like `DataTemplate` don't make any sense.

There is no problem at all binding to a specific property of an object. Period.